# Web API ReadFromStreamAsync not executed

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a very dumb issue related to a custom formatter.

```
public class RequestHeaderJsonFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public RequestHeaderJsonFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        return base.ReadFromStreamAsync(type, readStream, content, formatterLogger);
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
       return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I register the formatter in Global.asax as it follows:

protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new RequestHeaderJsonFormatter());

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

}

My issue is that ReadFromStreamAsync never gets called when executing the controller action.

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetString(string param)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "ererrer");
        return response;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong...I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default 'string' type action parameters are expected to be read from Uri, unless [FromBody] attribute is used to decorate it, in which case the formatters come into picture.

public HttpResponseMessage GetString(**[FromBody]**string param)

Comment: Hey, I apologize for my late reply. It doesn't work at all. I replaced the string parameter with an custom object and I have same behavior.

Comment: could you share how your raw request (from Fiddler probably) looks like?